# Mac OS X Active Directory tools

Tags: macos, active-directory

I'm looking into Active Directory tools for Mac, and what you can edit in command line. Not afraid of a bit of reading so if you have something good to read on the matter that'd be good.

Firstly, what are you able to update/create on AD either on AD or by creating an app

Secondly, does anyone know or use any apps to achieve this?

I've been looking into Manage Engine's AD Manager Plus, but I know you can at least unlock accounts using an app (AD Assist iPhone app)

Answer (score 0):

AD HelpDesk let's you do the same sort of stuff that AD Assist does from iOS, maybe more.

I haven't really looked at AD Assist too much.  AD HelpDesk also has a OSX desktop version that has some limited functionality, although it doesn't have nearly as many options on OSX as it does on iOS (and it isn't a command line tool)

If you want a really robust command line solution (and are willing to pay for it), check out http://software.dell.com/products/authentication-services/.

You can do just about anything you want using the command line tool, create users, change attributes.  You name it, it can probably be done.